# Run artisan command in Kernel.php

Tags: php, laravel, cron

i have installed a Laravel package for dumping my database.
The plugin runs find, but i want to run it every day as a cronjob.

Here is the inserted command in Kernel.php:

```
$schedule->command('db:backup')->dailyAt('01:50');
```

Unfortunately it hasn't done anything.
Is it possible to run an artisan command direct in the Kernel.php without a Command class ?

Comment: use `exec` as opposed to `command`. that should work.

Comment: can u give me an example how will look like my code with exec() ?

Comment: How do you normally call the command from the command line? is it `php artisan db:backup?` if so, then you can do the same in the `->exec()` statement.

Comment: but i need it as an cronjob. Look the code i have in the question

Comment: Yes, what's the issue? It's running `->dailyAt('01:50');`. Just use `exec()->` and chain `dailyAt->` off of it. OR are you saying the CRON never executes?

Comment: Use Git bash. Run the command. it will execute

Answer (score 2):

Have you made sure to add the task to your system crontab? Typically located at /etc/crontab

```
* * * * * php /path/to/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

From https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/scheduling

PHP has no way of executing itself, so you need to set up a system task to call artisan every second, so laravel can evaluate the cron expressions and run them as needed.